# Lock Chrome/Firefox with a password

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, password-protection

I want to have an option to protect my data and logins in the browsers, so that no one else that has access to the computer would be able to use my browser profile.
Something that will ask for a password when I open the browser on my profile (and even lock it again when idle).

I saw some solutions as plugins that do that, but I don't know how secure they are. For example, I saw [LockPW](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lockpw/pcddogkbbapgikkkbjaipefkbmlbofio) for chrome, but if delete the extension manually from chrome folder it will open the profile again. So I guess that it's better to have something that encrypt my data so it won't be useful if the extension got deleted that way.

I prefer a solution for chrome, but also Firefox is great.
I'm on windows 7 if that's matter.

Do you know of any solutions that could help me?

Thanks,
Ariel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Version 63.0.3239.84, you can add a new profile and then assign your main profile to supervise the new profile. This way, you will have the "Exit and child lock" option enable at the profile switcher drop-down.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3463947?hl=en

This solution only works for one profile. If you have multiple people sharing Chrome, only one gets to lock their profile.

Comment: but this is for chrome which doesn't support anymore. Is there any way in firefox?

Comment: Firefox doesn't seem to have this feature as far as I know.